# Stratified Sampling Total Statum

Tags: sampling, stratification

I wish to find the number of total population by each specification.
I have the following results:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
class    & n_h  \\\hline
Positive & 5872 \\\hline
Neutral  & 6771 \\\hline
Negative & 8724
\end{array}

where $n_h$ is the number of elements of the random sample of each class.

I wish to find the total population per class, how should I proceed?

Note that the sampling was done through random sampling.
I was employing the following formula.
$n_h = \frac{n N_h}{N}$ and using capture recapture to find the $N$

Comment: Please describe your exact sampling procedure, then I can help you with this.

Comment: Random Sampling

Comment: Random sampling from the entire population, or random sampling from each stratum?  If you started with a single simple random sample you didn't do a stratified random sample (NOTE:  It isn't a good idea to say 'random sampling'.  There are lots of random sampling techniques, including simple random samples, cluster samples, stratified samples, composite samples, etc.).  In other words, how EXACTLY did you take the sample?